# Updating selected value in RadioButtonList, ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

Could you please help me?, My idea is get a data from database into radiobuttonlist. As in the following code

```
 if (RadioButtonList2.Items.FindByValue(myReader["LO_interested"].ToString()) != null)
 {
    RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue = myReader["LO_interested"].ToString();
 }
```

Next the user can update his previous choice by selecting another value in radiobuttonlist, however there is a condition before updating new selected value.
My issue is radioButtonList does not select the value that the user clicked on it, the system still retains the old value.
this is the source code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" ToolTip="1-Video OR 2-Text OR 3-Game"  style="margin-bottom: 0px"  >
    <asp:ListItem Value="video/mp4">video</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="application/pdf">text</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="game/swf">game</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

the following code is the code behind C#

```
//update student preference and save it in database
void UpdateInfo()
{
    string interested = "";   
        if (RadioButtonList2.Items[0].Selected == true)
        { interested = "video/mp4"; }
        else if (RadioButtonList2.Items[1].Selected == true)
        { interested = "application/pdf"; }
        else if (RadioButtonList2.Items[2].Selected == true)
        { interested = "game/swf"; }
    string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AHSConnection"].ToString();
    using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        cn.Open();
        if (analyzeResultTable(lblStudentId.Text) != interested) 
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert(' ');</script>");
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Update student SET LO_interested='" + analyzeResultTable(lblStudentId.Text) + "' where S_Id = '" + Session["StudentId"].ToString() + "'", cn);
            var i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            //Update
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Update student SET LO_interested='" + interested + "' where S_Id = '" + Session["StudentId"].ToString() + "'", cn);
            var i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();             
        }
    }
}
```

And here calling update function:

```
 protected void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    UpdateInfo();
    RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex = -1;
 }
```

Comment: You have to show `analyzeResultTable`. You should also start to use parametrized queries.

Comment: But i suspect that your `Page_Load` contains code that always DataBinds the `RadioButtonList2` not only `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`. Then you have already the solution.

Comment: I used if(!Page.IsPostBack) on page_load and it is working well now:) Thank you.